# VBA excel convert value

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am using a connection to a CSV file to get the information in a XLS macro file 
and I am having the issue with this query:

```
DataQuery = "SELECT [LastName], [FirstName], [BadgeNum], IIF(IsNull([CaseDocs]), 0, [CaseDocs]),IIF(IsNull([CallCount]), 0, [CallCount]),  IIF(IsNull([DocRate]), 0, [DocRate])" & _
        "FROM [" & DataFileName & ".csv] WHERE CallCenterDescription='ECA' AND [LastName] LIKE '" & Sheets(1).Range("G1").Value & "%' AND DATEDIFF(dd,CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), [Date]), 112),getdate())  <= " & Sheets(1).Range("G2").Value & ""
```

the problem is `AND DATEDIFF(dd,CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), [Date]), 112),getdate())  <= " & Sheets(1).Range("G2").Value & ""`
in the where clause:Undefined CONVERT function

Answer (score 1):

you use different syntax for the same clause

```
CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), [Date]), 112)
```

maybe should be

```
DATEDIFF(dd, date, getdate())
```

or

```
DATEDIFF(dd, [Date], getdate())
```